# Import/AbsoluteFileName does not find file returned by FileNames on network folder

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I'm having some issue with `Import` and [`AbsoluteFileName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteFileName.html) used together with `FileNames`. Take for example this:

```
Through[{Import, AbsoluteFileName, FileExistsQ}@First@FileNames["*.txt"]]
```

When I `SetDirectory` to a local directory (e.g. `C:/Users/...`), this works, i.e. it returns `{"content","C:\Users\...",True}`. If instead I'm on a network folder (i.e. `//server/share/...`), I get either `{"content",$Failed,True}` or `{$Failed,$Failed,True}`. I have not yet been able to find any pattern to when it's working, and `AbsoluteFileName` seems to never work. I can be both results (failed and successful Import) on the same network share. The tested paths contain both spaces and no spaces, and no other special characters.

The network folder was added by going to "Add network address" in Windows Explorer.

The question now is: Why is `Import` sometimes failing, and how do I get `AbsoluteFileName` to work?

Comment: This is something support@wofram.com should know about

Comment: @halirutan I just wanted to ask here first in the case I missed something obvious. But I have reported the issue now, and will update the post if I hear back from them

Comment: `AbsoluteFileName` similarly fails if you explicitly give it the full path ( `\\\\server\\..` ). I haven't found an instance of `Import` failing though ( and I use for server files  so often I think I would have noticed.. )

Comment: It seems that 11.3 fixed all the issues I had... I will update MMA on a few more PCs in the next days and check there - if everything goes well, I'll close this as fixed